# Why should I use the variant prop instead of className in react bootstrap button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Why should I use the `variant` prop in react-bootstrap? Is it possible to use `className` instead to specify the button's styles?

```
const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button className="text-center" variant="primary w-100 fs-5 mb-2" type="submit"> Submit </Button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use bootstrap classes like w-100 fs-5 mb-2 etc on the Button component. Variant is a property which takes only certain values: 'primary', 'secondary', etc.

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/buttons/#button-props

> One or more button variant combinations
>
> buttons may be one of a variety of visual variants such as:
>
> 'primary', 'secondary', 'success', 'danger', 'warning', 'info',
> 'dark', 'light', 'link'
>
> as well as "outline" versions (prefixed by 'outline-*')
>
> 'outline-primary', 'outline-secondary', 'outline-success',
> 'outline-danger', 'outline-warning', 'outline-info', 'outline-dark',
> 'outline-light'

The property "variant" colors your button accordingly to your theme. It's not a bootstrap class but a property because react-bootstrap try to adopt React components as much as possible and tries to avoid classes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the `variant` string just gets injected into the class field as `btn-${variant}`, so as long as you use a string it'll pass.

As mentioned by Igor, the `variant` prop has been designed for you to add the button variant you're after, not as an alternative or addition to the `className` prop.

So yes, based on the current implementation of the `variant` prop your code will work, as long as you put the button variant you're after as the first part of the string. That said, it's not the ideal way to go about it.

```
variant="primary" className="w-100 fs-5 mb-2"
```

The above is better, less prone to breaking if the framework gets updated, and also gives a lot more clarity to anyone reading your code... that said, you're correct, with the current implementation of Button in React Bootstrap, there's no functional difference that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that people use variants to not write like 5 class names that's what I like to think.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).